How to add WNS secret to Azure Notification Hub?
I'm following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification to add push notification service to my UWP app. I have created a new app in Microsoft Partner Center. Now when i go to the WNS/PNS section and click on the App Registration Portal to create the Client Secret it is not redirecting to Azure portal as indicated in the reference,
instead im getting this error.
I have tried to login to azure portal using the same credentials as the Microsoft Partner Center(note i have not created a azure account with this credentials.) and it shows a AppRegistration with the same name as the one i have created in the Partner center. I created a client secret for this app and added that secret to WNS in Azure Notification Hub. It took the values and didnt throw any error. Now my UWP application is getting registered to Notification Hub but whenever I send a test notification it fails with
The Token obtained from the Token Provider is wrong.
I assumed this was error in app registration hence i created another app in the azure account(same as Partner account), but now it throws error when i try to use this client secret in the WNS of Notification Hub.
Since I have an actual azure account (different credentials) i tried regestering a new app with the same name as the App created in the partner center, again Notification Hub throws error when i use client secret from this app.
How should I properly configure this?
